# Load images from multiple subfolder by using keras ImageDataGenerator

Tags: python, keras

I am using keras ImageDataGenerator now. Below is my dataset structure

```
Train
  --subfolder 1
  ----label name
  ------image1.jpg
  ------image2.jpg
  --subfolder 2 
  ----label name
  ------image1.jpg
  ------image2.jpg
```

As structure, I have multiple subfolder and each subfolder have multiple label(or categories) and images.

I understood that ImageDataGenerator can get label name automatically, but if I adding a subfolder in my dataset structure then I can't train my dataset easily.
Can I simply modify ImageDataGenerator to match my dataset structure or is there any solution for this questions?

Thanks